# Unity Dependency could not be resolved on Model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am learning Unity, and create a very simple web api solution.

```
public interface IClass1
    {
        string GetItem();
    }

    public class Class1 : IClass1
    {
        public string GetItem() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

and then I use Unity to do IoC job such as:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterInstance<IClass1>(new Class1());

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

The code above works fine, if I want to get the dependency on Controller

```
[Dependency]
public IClass1 Class1Instance { get; set; }

[HttpGet]
[Route("Hello")]
public IHttpActionResult PutData()
{
    return Ok(Class1Instance.GetItem());
}
```

But if I try to do the same job on Model class, i.e. Base class.... I could not resolve....

```
public class Base
{
    [Dependency]
    public IClass1 ClassInstance { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetVal()
    {
        return ClassInstance.GetItem(); // ClassInstance is null
    }
}
```

I have no idea about that.... maybe the problem is from the jsonConverter....

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jobject = new JObject();
            object target;

            if (jobject.Property("Name") != null)
                target = new Base(); // Here is the problem root cause ??

            serializer.Populate(jobject.CreateReader(), target);
            return target;
        }
```

How to solve my problem if I want to get resolve dependency on Model class ??

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you think it is related to jsonconverter?

Comment: I just guess, I just have no idea why I could not resolve the dependency on Model class

Comment: To extend @CodingYoshi's question, why do you think it is jsonConverter? Did you get an exception related to resolving jsonConverter? Can you provide us with any exception details that might help narrow down the issue?

Comment: @ninjacoder no.... there is no exception in jsonConverter.... I just randomly guess the root cause....

Comment: @allencharp you are manually initializing the class `Base` It is in no way associated with the container so there is nothing to inject. The IoC container is not being used so it won't inject anything.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for your explaination, is there any way to solve the proble....thanks

Comment: @allencharp Pass the resolver to the custom converter. Register the Base class with the container to be resolved per request. Have the resolver resolve the Base class and inject dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand of your question, I think the missing link in your solution is the `controller`. Setting the `DependencyResolver` is indeed a required step. Without knowing your code for the `UnityDependencyResolver`, I'll assume that part is correct. What is missing in the code you provided is the ``controller` class. Create it such as :

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Whatever")]
    public TestController(IClass1 class1)
    {
        // At this point, your class1 will have been
        // instantiated by Unity.
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("EvenMore")]
    public HttpResponseMessage EvenMore(string foo)
    {
    }
}
```

Do that, put a breakpoint in the constructor there, and call EvenMore. If it doesn't work, update your question with any other informations you might have.